# Can't create contact with javascript on Google contacts api v3

Tags: javascript, google-contacts-api

With the following code all my contacts are created empty, (no name, no email, nothing). My guess it that my json structure is wrong. The contacts API v3 provides no information on how this schema is structured in json and I can't find it after much searching. Does someone know this?

The GoogleApi method is from a meteor package see : https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-google-api
it's basically a wrapper around http to simplify access token auto-refresh.

```
GoogleApi.post('/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full', {
          data: {
              name: {
                "displayName": "Firstname",
                "givenName": "Firstname",
                "familyName": "FamilyName",
                "fullName": "FullName"
              },
              emailAddresses: [{
                Primary: true,
                Address: "rest@test.com",
                DisplayName: "displayed name"
            }],
              city: "testcity",
              street: "Test Street 11",
              postcode: "111",
              country: "test",
          }, function(error, answer) {
    if (error) {console.log(error)}
    if (answer) {console.log(answer)}
  });
```

Comment: Did you success with it ? It makes me mad! I don't really know which data should I fill in my JSON, even when I'm inspiring with the GET result

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can probably do is just read a contact with GET, instead of creating one with POST just so you can look at it. The response JSON will be identical to the JSON you should be constructing to create a contact. The format itself is rather complicated and nuanced (because it's in a round-trip format to the XML version including all the fiddly XML namespaces) and so it's not something you can guess.

Comment: good point .. hwever Google should deliver a better documentation search engine... ( doc is so hge and changing...) to travel among all their APIs ...